# Adding icons to toolbar in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to set my menu Icons in Android to the Left in the Toolbar. Isn't working.

```
package com.vrobinde.reminderapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuInflater

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Override
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_icons, menu);

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Line 21:** MenuInflater gets underlined in Red, the equal-symbol gets underlined red and the closed bracket gets underlined red. 
**Line 22:** Inflater is red

I'm using AndroidX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing java and kotlin:

In kotlin:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_icons, menu)
        return true
    }
```

In java:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_icons, menu);
        return true;
    }
```